# Any tool for check the result of migration from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps to ensure that everything was successfully migrated?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs

We are planning to migrate over from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps, and the task assigned to me is to find out the way to do a comparison after the migration between what we have on TFS and Azure to ensure that all the tasks, bugs, etc was successfully migrated over. I've checked with the Guide from Azure and found nothing about such post migration checking and comparison. Is there any tool for this or we can only do the whole checking and comparison manually?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool.

I have never experienced a partial migration. Due to the way the import works that is also VERY unlikely. Either the complete import fails, or the data is going to be there. I've done many of these migrations as well as server migrations/upgrades and the kind  of data-loss you're worried about has never happened.

The one thing you'd need to be careful of [are the changes to the retention policies](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/safely-upgrade-from-azure-devops-server-2019-to-server-2020/?msclkid=f0034acdd16211ec9388070ec82b3730&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511).